# Reading a user-created dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays

How would you create a function that would read a dynamic array that is created by the user, with values also being put in by the user?

```
int main() {

    int choice;
    int choice2;
    bool confirm = true;
    bool confirm2 = true;
    int *array1 = NULL;
    int *array2 = NULL;
    while(confirm==true){

        if (choice > 0)
        {
            array1 = new int[choice];
            confirm = false;
        }
        else if(choice <= 0)
        {
            cout<<"Try again, positive numbers only" << endl;
        }
    }
    //get size for 2nd array
    while (confirm2 == true){

        cout << "Input a number for array size for array 2: " << endl;
        cin >> choice2;

        if (choice2 > 0)
        {
            array2 = new int[choice2];
            confirm2 = false;
        }
        else if (choice2 <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Try again, positive numbers only" << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "Enter numeric values into the array" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++)
    {
        int item;
        cout << "Enter a numeric for item " << i << endl;
        cin >> item;
        *(array1 + i) = item;
    }
}
```

My problem in this one is that I don't know if its possible to create a function that would read and modify the array that has been created by the user.

Comment: Google `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy, if you are still stuck, the `std::vector` implementation provides a flexible container that can be use just like a traditional C-array, but also provides constructors and member functions to fill, expand and iterate over an unknown number of input from the user. To create an empty container, all you need is:

```
std::vector<int> v;   /* to create an empty vector container v */
```

(**note:** the varying constructors allow you to initialize all members, fill, copy from another array, etc.. at the time of declaration.)

Using a `typedef` can eliminate the need to repeatedly type `std::vector<type>` by creating an alias from a convenient label, e.g.

```
typedef std::vector<int> ivec_t;
```

(You can now use `ivect_t` in place of `std::vector<int>`)

Since you are dealing with an unknown number of inputs, the `push_back` function that adds the value pushed to the vector as the next element. For example to read an unknown number of integer values from `stdin` and add them to your vector, you could do:

```
ivec_t v;     /* declares an empty vector of integers container */
int n;

while (std::cin >> n)   /* for each value read on stdin  */
    v.push_back(n);     /* push the value into the array */
```

Now you have all integer values stored in your container. To access each, you can use the standard array notation of `v[x]` where `0 <= X < nelements`. However to iterate over your list,  an iterator can be used with the starting and ending element addresses provided by the member functions `begin()` and `end()`. So to access each value in your container, you could simply do:

```
/* use an iterator from begin to end to outpu stored values */
for (auto it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); it++)
    std::cout << " " << *it;    /* dereference iterator for value */
std::cout << "\n";
```

Putting it altogether, you can read an unknown number of integer values from `stdin` into your vector container with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> ivec_t;

int main (void) {

    ivec_t v;     /* declares an empty vector of integers container */
    int n;

    while (std::cin >> n)   /* for each value read on stdin  */
        v.push_back(n);     /* push the value into the array */

    /* use an iterator from begin to end to outpu stored values */
    for (auto it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); it++)
        std::cout << " " << *it;    /* dereference iterator for value */
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "2 4 6 8 10" | ./bin/vector_push_back
 2 4 6 8 10
```

**Using a Range-based Loop**

As pointed out by Sean in the comments, you can simplify the iteration using a range-based loop to iterate over the values in `v`. This can be done by value, reference or forward-reference, e.g.

```
    /* iterating over the values in v using access by value */
    for (auto i : v)
        std::cout << " " << i;    /* dereference iterator for value */
    std::cout << "\n";
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Why not use a new-style for loop to iterate over the elements? for(auto choice : v) is a lot simpler than manually incrementing an iterator. You only need to use your style of loop if you need to manipulate the iterator location within the loop.

Comment: Just typically because any vector reference will show the use of `begin()` and `end()`, but much fewer have the newer loop control explained. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the basic read over pointer and adjust memories and reassign, quite a hassle frankly, but thanks for the advice. I'm gonna look over vectors right now and try to get ahead. As much as I want to use vectors though, my professors require we complete these project assignments without the use of anything beyond what we should know yet.